# Why is this answer wrong. Double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $R$ be the region bounded by the $4$ lines:$y=x+1, y+x-1, y=-x+1, y=-x-1$

Calculate $$\iint_R 3x^2 ~dxdy$$

My answer:

$R=\{(x,y):-1 \leq x \leq 1, -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$ so then $$\iint_R 3x^2 ~dxdy=\int_{-1}^1dy\int_{-1}^13x^2 dx=2\times2=4$$ but the book says the answer is $1$? How am I wrong?

Comment: The region is not a square parallel to the axes! Draw those four lines and look again.

Comment: Okay my bad I wrote the region down wrong :(

Comment: More over i think you'd have to expression y as a function of x in limits and set x as free variable or vice versa.